# How do circular dependencies occur in C++?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I've been reading Design Patterns(GOF) and in it it's mentioned that Facade pattern eliminates circular dependencies.

I want to know how do they come in picture in C++?

PS: I am not asking how can I resolve them.

Comment: A requires B to compile. B requires A to compile. Only one of the two can be defined first, and it cannot be defined without the other having already been defined. Thus neither can be defined. Facade can break this loop by inserting a layer of abstraction between A and B, but that's not the usual goal of Facade: simplifying the complex.

Comment: @user4581301...Do circular dependencies come in play only during compilation? I mean does it occur only in physical program structure situation or also in a logical program structure situation too?

Comment: You can build circular dependencies into runtime through bad logic, but I described, and I believe Facade is primarily concerned with, the compile-time sort.

Comment: Doesn't the name kind of give it away? Certainly the [WIkipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) suitably answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ClassA.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_A_H
#define CLASS_A_H

#include "ClassB.h" // Contributes To Circular Include

class ClassA {
private:
    ClassB* m_pB;

public:
    explicit ClassA( ClassB* pB );

}; // ClassA

#endif // CLASS_A_H
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
#include "ClassA.h"
```

**ClassB.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_B_H
#define CLASS_B_H

#include "ClassA.h" // Contributes To Circular Include

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB();

    void updateA( ClassA* pA );

}; // ClassB

#endif // CLASS_B_H
```

**ClassB.cpp**

```
#include "ClassB.h"
```

What causes the circular dependencies is when one class includes the header file of another class within its own header file where the other class is also including the previous header file. This can also happen if multiple classes are involved where it may not be apparent but is done through a chain of includes for example:

`A.h includes B.h : B.h includes C.h : C.h includes D.h : D.h includes A.h` This still creates the circular dependency.

This is why it is advisable to have class prototypes or forward declarations in the header file of the class that depends on them; then to include those dependencies headers within the class's cpp file that requires those dependencies. There may be several cases where you can't not avoid this and that the included header has to be within the class's header, so this is why care needs to be taken towards a good program design.

Comment: Since you are using a pointer member rather than object member, this circular dependency can be avoided using forward declaration in the header and move includes to cpp files.

Comment: @user3528438 I did state that towards the bottom of my answer, but the OP didn't ask how to fix it, they did ask what causes or generates it.

Comment: Fixed typo in original answer.